# Dispelling Arcane Lock

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, duration

The duration on  [Arcane Lock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcane-lock) is listed as "until dispelled". If I cast Arcane Lock, then have a long rest and remove Arcane Lock from my list of spells, does it become dispelled?

Comment: Imagine how annoying it'd be if your sealed vault of demons came unlocked every time you took a nap.

Answer (score 11):

#### “Until dispelled” refers to the *dispel magic* spell (or any feature which explicitly ends magical effects).

The phrase “until dispelled” refers to the spell *dispel magic*:

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends. For each spell of 4th level or higher on the target, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell's level. On a successful check, the spell ends.

There may also be similar effects with different names that explicitly end a magical effect. So “until dispelled” means “until another effect says the spell ends”.

Changing your prepared spell list is not one of these effects, so changing your prepared spells has no effect on a “until dispelled” spell effect.

Comment: The text of Arcane Lock also indicates the spell ends if the object it was cast on is destroyed. So if you have Arcane Lock cast on a door or window, someone could destroy the door/window and pass through, and then cast Make Whole to repair it, but the Arcane Lock would not be automatically restored.